# Starting Emacs on OSX stuck

Tags: osx, start-up

When lots of application running, emacs doesn't start. Icon appears on dock but application doesn't show up. If I quit some apps and retry to start emacs, it works flawlessly.

Is the any chance to avoid this problem except quitting other apps?

I use standard emacs 25.0.50.

Comment: I've often seen this behavior on earlier Emacs versions, like 24.4, as well. I recently bought more RAM, and I believe the problem is less frequent now. I would suggest that you report this as a bug to the maintainers of Emacs.

Comment: It is my understanding that 25.0.50 is experimental, not standard.  The current stable public release is 24.5:  http://emacsformacosx.com/